# How to add Wrapper Component on a .vue file in vuejs 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can i implement vuejs doc site given example to a .vue component?

[this example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html)

I want to use simple jquery select2 plugin inside my form in a .vue component.

But the doc site given example is not clear to use in in .vue component.

Answer (score 0):

From the example on the Vue Site, you need to install select2 as a dependency and import it in your .vue component to use it.

```
import select2 from 'select2';
```

or you import it globally as chrisvfritz did it his example. You can see the whole setup in JSFiddle:
[implementation of Vue example by chrisvfritz](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/d131Lebj/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=d131Lebj) in the Ressource section you can see the dependencies. Seems like JQuery is a dependency too ;)

Comment: I found this jsfiddle before. But i am comfused how can i add this `<script type="text/x-template" id="demo-template">` in my .vue file ?